# How to remove elements from array of an embedded document which are not in my array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my document.

```
{
    "group_name" : "Test Group 6 (Edit)",
    "created_on" : "1464367826787",
    "group_id" : "group_14",
    "members" : [
        {
            "user_id" : "user_7",
            "added_on" : "1464367826787"
        }
    ],
    "is_deleted" : 0
}
```

I'm having list of user_ids and I need to remove user_ids which are not in the list of user_ids I have. How to remove "user_50" if input `list = ["user_7"]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator to select your documents, the [`updateMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) method if you want to update multiple documents or [`updateOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) method to update a single document.

```
db.users.updateMany(
    {}, 
    { "$pull": { "members": { "user_id":  { "$nin": [ "user_7" ] } } }} 
)
```

Comment: thanks, i tried with "members.user_id". typo in my code

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.update(
   {},
   {$pull:
   {members:{'user_id':{$ne:"user_7"}}}}, {multi:true})
```

Comment: input might be a list so we should use "$nin" rather than "$ne"